# bootstrap responsive tabs doesn't looks fine on mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

I like the system of responsive tabs but is not the same looking in a mobile device,fonts are smaller and margins greater. when resize the navigator window in a laptop looks perfect.

Why this difference? please helpme ;)

https://github.com/openam/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/issues/33

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you explain a little more instead of providing just links. It is advised to add as much as information you can in your questions/answers because links may be removed or may not wok due to some reasons.

Comment: Very hard to know just by looking at the screen shot - but it isn't typical bootstrap behaviour. Can you show more of your code? If i had to guess i'd say it has something to do with your viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Fonts are not responsive. Mobile devices have more pixels per inch than most laptops, sometimes up to a 2:1 ratio. This means the font may look half the size on a mobile device as it would on a laptop.

This is why the font looks good while resizing the browser however once you emulate a mobile device the font shrinks.

More information available here: [Web Design for Smart Phone - Pixel Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723039/web-design-for-smart-phone-pixel-size)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to everybody , i have a little big mistake !!!!!!!

**NEVER ,NEVER ,NEVER FORGET TO PUT THIS :**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

thats was all the problem ;)