# Size of viewport for an angular mobile app

Tags: angular, mobile

I am learning angular 2 (now angular) and I want to create a mobile app. So I was wondering about the size that I should use to fit correctly the smartphones.

Do I have to use a 16:9 size or there is a standard?

I dont want to start programming my app without knowing this and then when I compile everything found that it does not fit well the screens...

I've searched a lot but I don't find anything about this so maybe this is a newbie question. Sorry if it is.

I also think that I could try just to use dinamic measures like 100vh and 100vw and then percentages.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap framework has col-sm and col-xs classes to help with responsive design. Important to note sizing does vary slightly with mobile devices. Related stackoverflow question here [Web Design for Smart Phone - Pixel Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723039/web-design-for-smart-phone-pixel-size)